# I/O issues writing on file

Tags: c, io, system-calls

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why this piece of code doesn't work as it should. I am learning the basics of I/O operations and I have to come up with a C program that writes on a 'log.txt' file what is given from standard input and as the 'stop' word is entered, the program must halt.

So my code is:

```
#include "main.h"
#define SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int readBytes;
    int writBytes;
    char *buffer;

    if ((fd = open("log.txt", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("open");
    }

    buffer = (char *) calloc (SIZE, sizeof(char));
    while ((readBytes = read(0, buffer, SIZE) < SIZE)&&(strncmp(buffer, "stop", 4) != 0));

    if ((writBytes = write(fd, buffer, SIZE)) < 0)
    {
        perror("write");
    }

    if ((close(fd)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("close");
    }
}
```

If I enter:

```
this is just a text
stop
```

The output is

```
stop
is just a text
```

If I enter more than a sentence:

```
this is just a text
this is more text
and text again
stop
```

This is what is logged:

```
stop
ext again
xt
t
```

And on top of that if I try to edit the log.txt file from vim or just a text editor I can see '\00's. I guess \00 stands for all the bytes left empty from the 1024 available, right? How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting

```
readBytes = read(0, buffer, SIZE) < SIZE)
```

to somehow accumulate things in buffer. It doesn't. Every subsequent `read` will put whatever it read at the start of the buffer, overwriting what the previous `read` has read.

You need to put your `write` in the `while` block - one write for every read, and only `write` as much as you `read`, otherwise you'll write garbage (zeros from the `calloc` and/or leftovers from the previous read) in your log file.

Also note that while your technique will probably work most of the time for a line-buffered input stream, it will not do what you expect if you redirect from a file or a pipe. You should be using formatted input functions (like `getline` if you your implementation has that, `scanf`, or `fgets`).

Comment: I know it's kind of off-topic but what exactly are these open/read/write functions and where are they defined? They seem to resemble their fread e.t.c. counterparts.

Comment: `read` and `write` are in `<unistd.h>`, `open` in `<fcntl.h>`. `man 2 open` to see the man page - section 2: system calls.

Comment: @Mat thank you for your advice, I had this misconception that the read had to accumulate things in the buffer before writing, so I'm very pleased you cleared that out for me. I have another question though if I may. As long as I input sentences without hitting the return button, the logging works flawlessly, but if I need to hit it some pieces of previous sentences might be logged as well. Do I need in some way to clean the buffer before writing in the log file as I hit enter?

Comment: No you don't need to clear anything, but you must make sure you're writing only as much as you have read. `readBytes` should appear in your `write` calls, not `SIZE`.

Comment: @Mat I've just tried what you suggested and the issue seems to be still unsolved. I have modified my code in this way:

`while (readBytes = read(0, buffer, SIZE)&&(strncmp(buffer, "stop", 4) != 0))
 {
   while ((writBytes = write(fd, buffer, SIZE)) < readBytes);
 }`

but still there are unwanted strings from previous sentences logged.

Comment: `SIZE` must not appear at all in your write calls. You **must not** write `SIZE` bytes. You can only write `<= readBytes` bytes. And that second `while` has the same problem as your initial `read` loop. `write` will write from the start of the buffer each time.

Comment: @Mat I'm so sorry, I feel pretty dumb right now but I have to admit a bit confused. I totally understand why write loop needs to match in size the read bytes, so the I should change my code this way:

`while ((writBytes = write(fd, buffer, readBytes)) < readBytes);`

I don't get what should be the third parameter as I invoke the read call, given that all I know is my buffer size and I cannot possibly know the amount of bytes that are gonna be put in.

Comment: The last parameter to **read** is the buffer size. So SIZE is ok. The last parameter to **write** is how many bytes to extract from the buffer. That must never be greater than what you read into that buffer, and never greater than SIZE.